# Java: Word search program, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I've been working a word search program for a while now. Ittakes a text file as input such as:

```
7 //number of rows
15 // number of columns
mucatpoltqfegkq
hfytpnsdlhcorey
pgrhdqsypyscped
gkagdntorioapje
yerjodxnqzztfmf
hypmmgoronkzhuo
qrtzaulhtgtqaao
```

And then looks for the word the user enters. The file reading and array creation takes place in a separate class.

Now, I need to make it find the words horizontally from left to right, downwards, and diagonally from upper left to lower right. What I'm trying to do is first find where the first letter occurs and then start evaluating the rest of the word from that position.

What I've done up to now only works sometimes. I'm able to find "cat" vertically on the first row, but when I try to find pizza diagonally I get an out of bounds error. I know this means that something is going beyond the array, and I know how to fix it in more simple programs(like a for-loop that goes through an array), but not here.

I haven't started on the `checkDown` method because I'd like to get the problems I have now figured out. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordSearch
{
    private char[][] array;
    private String targetWord;
    private int rowLocation;
    private int colLocation;

    public WordSearch(char[][] inArray)
    {
        array = inArray;
        for (int row = 0; row < inArray.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < inArray[row].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.print(inArray[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void play()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("What word would you like to search for? Type end to quit: ");
        targetWord = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Typed in: " + targetWord);
        System.out.println();

        compareFirst(targetWord);

    }

    public void compareFirst(String inWord)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++)
            {
                if(array[row][col] == inWord.charAt(0))
                {
                    rowLocation = row;
                    colLocation = col;

                    suspectAnalysis();
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void suspectAnalysis()
    {
        checkRight();
        checkDown();
        checkDiagonal();
    }

    public void checkRight()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(array[rowLocation][colLocation + i] == targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
                System.out.println(targetWord + " found horizontally at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
            }
        }

    }

    public void checkDown()
    {
        //code goes here
    }

    public void checkDiagonal()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < (targetWord.length()); i++)
        {
            if(array[rowLocation + i][colLocation + i] == targetWord.charAt(i))
            {
                System.out.println(targetWord + " found diagonally at row " + rowLocation + " and column " + colLocation);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: When you "scan" the array, you have to check if you reach outside the boundaries of the array. That's pretty simple. `colLocation + i` is too far outside of the array, so you get an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **checkDiagonal()** method is going `outOfBounds` because u have not added a condition to check whether your `[rowLocation+i]` and `[colLocation+i]` are in bounds of array. Add this condition and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

What the comment above said: `if(array[rowLocation][colLocation + i] == targetWord.charAt(i))` seems suspicious.

What happens if your word is aligned vertically along the right-hand side of the grid? You should consider adding an `if` statement before that one to check if `[rowLocation + i][colLocation + i]` is within bounds. If not, you can be sure that the word is not aligned that way (be it within your `checkRight()` or `checkDiagonal()` function) and you can exit the loop and return from the function to check another direction.